# Comparar cadenas de caracteres

Tags: c

Estoy intentando comparar una cadena de caracteres que recibo por UART que envío a través de un bash por Linux. La cadena se supone que es una contraseña para poder acceder a un estado "especial". La longitud de la contraseña es de 8 caracteres (contraseña = "password"). El código correspondiente con el bash es el siguiente:

```
[zZ] )  echo -e  "SET_PASSWORD"
        read -n8 -r -p "Introduce password [********]: " PASSWORD
        echo -e -n "\x02\x01\xCSET_PASSWORD"${PASSWORD} > "${1}"
        ;;
```

Los valores "\x02\x01\xC..." son cabeceras. En otras partes donde envío estos comando funciona correctamente. Así que no lo tengáis en cuenta.

Por otro lado, el código en C en mi sistema (donde recibo la cadena por UART) es el siguiente:

```
#define PASSWORD password
funcion_uart()
{
char password[8];

// tratamiento de la trama (cabecera, comando, etc)
// Aquí llega la parte que compara la cadena enviada en función del comando enviado del bash
case RESETDATALOGGER:
{
   printf("Password command received\n");
   // Copio la cadena recibida en "password"
   strncpy(password, &(serialData.rx_buffer.cmd.str[strlen(LIST_OF_COMMANDS[SET_PASSWORD]) + 1]), 8);
   // Último caracter para cerrar la cadena
   password[8] = '\0';
                        
   if( (strncmp(password, PASSWORD, 9)) == 0 )
   {
       printf("Right password\n");
   }
   else
   {
       printf("Wrong password\n");
   }
                        
   break;
} // end case
} // end function
```

Siempre que envío por el bash la cadena me sale el mensaje de "Wrong password". Da igual que utilice mayúsculas, minúsculas, etc. En teoría, si envío la palabra "password" la función `strcmp()` retornaría '0' y por lo tanto imprimir por pantalla "Right password".

¿Alguna sugerencia sobre por qué no me está comparando bien la cadena?

Muchas gracias y un saludo.

Comment: Por si acaso hay un espacio antes e l carácter de redirecciono `..."${PASSWORD} > "${1}` el espacio entre `}` y `>` se incluirå. Quizá por ahí viene que el password siempre es errado

Comment: La función `strncmp` funciona correctamente, así que lo más probable es que la cadena no sea como tu esperas. Quizás le falta el finalizador de cadena. ¿Has probado a hacer un `printf` de `password` a ver qué tiene? ¿Has probado a analizar la cadena con un depurador?

Comment: Por qué el strcmp tiene un longitud de comparación 9 si el password tiene 8?

Comment: Si mandas password no va a ser igual porqu la comparación es sobre 9 caracteres. En el oro caso e vería ser strlen(password). Si le añades el espacio del echo no vas a tener contraseñas iguales. Tu programa funciona bien en es aspecto

Comment: Estoy imprimiendo la cadena "password" que genero al copiar lo que recibo por UART. El primer carácter no aparece, es decir, si en el bash envío `HOLAHOLA`, lo que copio en la cadena "password" es `OLAHOLA`. El error estaba en `strncpy(password, &(serialData.rx_buffer.cmd.str[strlen(LIST_OF_COMMANDS[SET_PASSWORD]) + 1]), 8);`. Más concretamente el '+1'. Está solucionado, muchas gracias a todos!